# How to save a session without password in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-7

I'm building an application that doesn't need a login page because the server already asks for an sso and a password when accessing to any app in the server. The problem is that i need to save the user session but the sso api only gives me the ID of the user, so i was wondering how do i do that in Laravel 7?

I was thinking on a route `/login/{id}` that generates a token and saves it in the browser session and the database, and in every request the system verifies if the token is the same. I don't know if there is a better way to save a session without password, and how to do it in php using Laravel methods.

Thank you.

Comment: the token gives you the same id every time a use login? or if the same user login 2 times you get 2 different tokens?

Comment: I don't know haha, maybe i should delete the token if the user logs in again and generate a new one

Comment: which SSO are you using?

Comment: Not sure, is from the company i work on, i don't have access to its documentation :(